# Image Cropping in rectangle shape and it shud move

Tags: ios, image, imageview, crop

I want to crop an UIImageView in rectangular size and it Should be resizable, Please anyone help me, I am struggling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to add pan gesture from which you can move the imageview and pinch gesture through which you can resize the image

```
-(void)addGesture {
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
    [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [imgView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

     UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(resize:)];
        [imgView addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];

}

-(void)move:(id)sender {
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender view]];
    CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:self.view];

    if ([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        firstX = [[sender view] center].x;
        firstY = [[sender view] center].y;
    }

    translatedPoint = CGPointMake(firstX+translatedPoint.x, firstY);

    [[sender view] setCenter:translatedPoint];
}

- (void)resize:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{

    if([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        _lastScale = 1.0;
        if ([recognizer numberOfTouches] >= 2) { //should always be true when using a PinchGR
            CGPoint touch1 = [recognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:self.imageForEditing];
            CGPoint touch2 = [recognizer locationOfTouch:1 inView:self.imageForEditing];
            CGPoint mid;
            mid.x = ((touch2.x - touch1.x) / 2) + touch1.x;
            mid.y = ((touch2.y - touch1.y) / 2) + touch1.y;
            CGSize imageViewSize = self.imageForEditing.frame.size;
            CGPoint anchor;
            anchor.x = mid.x / imageViewSize.width;
            anchor.y = mid.y / imageViewSize.height;
            self.imageForEditing.layer.anchorPoint = anchor;
        }
    }

    CGFloat scale = 1.0 - (_lastScale - [recognizer scale]);

    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = self.imageForEditing.transform;
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, scale, scale);

    [self.imageForEditing setTransform:newTransform];

    _lastScale = [recognizer scale];


}
```

Comment: I need to Crop Image and overlay should be resizable and movable

Comment: You can use Below Code:

// Returns image resized to the desired CGSize
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}

Comment: i want it to be moved by touch ,send me code iam beginner pls help me

Comment: Thanks It worked but i want it to be resize by moving corner of image

Comment: Then you need to add four small custom view on each corner of the UIImageView and handle touches on all views programatically

Like you are trying to scale image using top right corner view then you just need to increase/decrease origin x & y and also increase/decrease width and height according to the ratio, but many codes are available for this